# How to gather functions which intersect at the same point?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, challenge-community

How to gather functions which intersect at the same point (real solution)?

```
func = {2 x, x^2 + 1, (x^3 + 3)/2};
```

[image]

For example, with the list of functions above I want it to be divided into 3 groups as follows:
(I'm not sure if I missed any, I just looked at the plot to group them)

```
out= {{2 x, x^2 + 1, (x^3 + 3)/2}, {2 x, (x^3 + 3)/2}, { x^2 + 1, (x^3 + 3)/2}}
```

EDIT:
rhermans gave a nice answer. However, I didn't know that the number of functions would change the approach. I should have mentioned that in my case, the number of functions is quite large, probably 100 or more.
So some apporach may work very nice for small number of functions but  cause insufficient memory with large number of functions.

Comment: Why not group like this: `sb2 = Subsets[func, {2}]` ? Then subtract, set to zero, solve and find that the common point of intersection for each pair is at `x->1`.

Comment: @Syed In the example above, I just gave a simple example of 3 functions but there are probably more than 2 functions intersect.

Comment: @Syed made a nice suggestion. You can use `new=Equal @@@ Subsets[func, {2}]` to get all possible equations. Then, `Solve@new` gives one solution which is where all three meet and `Solve /@ new` gives the remaining solutions. Then you can group them. Is this roughly what you meant?

Comment: @bmf yes, I think so. Thinking about Syed suggestion, I think I can make every subsets of two functions, solve them and save the intersection point. Then I can check intersection points for all subsets to combine them to get groups of 3 functions or more. 
One problem is that they normally intersect at more than one points so make it more complicated but I think it should work.

Comment: @emnha The way the question is described, one need to go trough all possible combinations of equations. Which is too many for such long list. Can you constraint the grouping criteria somehow?

Comment: @emnha based on your edit you want to create all subsets with at least two elements and up to and including all elements of a list that contains your function. With `func = {2 x, 3 x, 5 x, x^2, x^2 + 1, (x^3 + 3)/2, x^3, x^5, Log[x], 
   Exp[x]};` if you do `Subsets[func, {2, Length@func}]` you have more than `1000` entries. Not sure if `Solve` is efficient for that.

Comment: @rhermans the only contraint  I can think of is that it should return the maximum number of functions intersect at the same point. For example, if you have `{function1, function2, function3}` intersect at the point `{x0, y0}` the you would return only  `{x0, y0}->{function1, function2, function3}` not `{x0, y0}->{function1, function2}` or`{x0, y0}->{function1, function3}` etc. But you already did that in your answer.

Comment: @bmf `Subsets[func, {2, Length@func}]` would cause insufficient memory already if the number of function is like 50.

Comment: The number of  `Subsets` of length two or larger  is $2^n-n -1$, for $n=100$ that is more than $10^{30}$ Subsets. Too many to be manageble, a different approach is needed.

Comment: @rhermans yes, thanks for making the statement explicit. the reason I brought it up was because there were the comments by myself and Syed. just to clarify that after the edit the suggestion is inefficient

Comment: Posted another answer, but it's cumbersome and surely could be made more efficiency by somebody else. Anybody up for the challenge?

Answer (score 4):

This goes through all $2^n -n -1$ subsets of length 2 or more. An overkill that allows very simple code, but it's not practical for large $n$. See other answer(s).

```
func = {2 x, x^2 + 1, (x^3 + 3)/2};
GroupBy[
    Subsets[func, {2,Infinity}]
    , N[x/.Solve[Equal@@#, Reals]]&
]
```

> ```
> <|
>     {1., 1.} -> {{2 x, 1 + x^2}},
>     {1., -2.30278, 1.30278} -> {{2 x, 1/2 (3 + x^3)}},
>     {1., -0.618034, 1.61803} -> {{1 + x^2, 1/2 (3 + x^3)}},
>     {1.} -> {{2 x, 1 + x^2, 1/2 (3 + x^3)}}
> |>
> ```

This should be interpretes as

- Functions  `{2 x, 1 + x^2}` all intercept only at `{1., 1.}`
- Functions  `{2 x, 1/2 (3 + x^3)}` all intercept only at `{1., -2.30278, 1.30278}`
- Functions  `{1 + x^2, 1/2 (3 + x^3)}` all intercept only at `{1., -0.618034, 1.61803}`
- Functions  `{2 x, 1 + x^2, 1/2 (3 + x^3)}` all intercept only at `{1.}`

Or probably, depending what you mean

```
Union@@@GroupBy[
    Subsets[func, {2,Infinity}]
    , Union[N[x/.Solve[Equal@@#, Reals]]]&
]
```

> ```
> <|
>     {1.} -> {2 x, 1 + x^2, 1/2 (3 + x^3)},
>     {-2.30278, 1., 1.30278} -> {2 x, 1/2 (3 + x^3)}, 
>     {-0.618034, 1., 1.61803} -> {1 + x^2, 1/2 (3 + x^3)}
> |>
> ```

Comment: nice solution, somehow I thought that we need one equation for one variable so two or equations for one variable would make no solution.

Comment: One problem with this is that it requires too much memory for a large number of functions. I just tried with 48 functions and the computation was aborted due to insufficient memory.

Comment: Well, this is just a first approach, you didn't mentioned complexity of expressions or any other constraints before.

Comment: Yes,  you're right. The code is nice for small number of functions. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

This goes only through all  $(n^2-n)/2$ `Subsets[func, {2}]` as suggested by @Syed. For $n=100$ that is only $4950$ cases.

It calculates the intersection points of all equation pairs. Then it `check`s if a particular point liven in each function. Then it groups the functions based on which intersection points they share.

```
ClearAll[check];
check[expr_][ pnt_] := Equal[expr/.x->First[pnt], Last[pnt]]

With[
    {
        pntlist = Union@Flatten[{x, First[#]}/.Solve[Equal@@#,x,Reals]& /@Subsets[func, {2}],1]
    },
    GroupBy[Last->First]@
    Flatten[
        Table[
            {e,#}& /@ Select[pntlist, check[e]]
            , {e, func}]
        ,1
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Looking forward reading more efficient solutions!